# Transfer ownership of a vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a good way to transfer the ownership of an extension from one account to another? Or do I still have to create a new one and deprecate the old one?

Comment: and you have to notify your users of the new name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ship a new extension which can run on its own with all functionalities.
2. Ship a new release of your old extension, where you remove all functionalities and the sole feature is to detect if the user installed the new extension. And if not yet installed, the old extension can automatically install the new one (via VSCode standard API).

The necessary technical details can be found in [this blog](https://blog.lextudio.com/different-ways-to-create-vscode-extension-dependencies/).

Comment: Thanks, but why is there are still no feature to easily transfer the ownership?

Comment: @DanielToplak that can only be answered by Microsoft VSCode Marketplace team.